# Python min() of arguments with different types

Tags: python

I was surprised recently to find that you can take the min() of arguments of different types in Python and not get a ValueError.

```
min(3, "blah") ==> 3
min(300, 'zzz') ==> 300
```

The documentation is unclear on this - it just says min() takes "the smallest of the arguments". How is it actually determining which element is the smallest?

Answer (score 1):

It determines this by comparing them using the usual rules. If objects are of different types and can't be compared sensibly (because neither of them implement the required special methods, or the implementation doesn't work with the type of the other object) then they are given a consistent order by type; e.g., all integers are less than all strings. Try it: `1 < "1"`

(By the way, Booleans are implemented as a subclass of integers, and can be compared with numbers, so they'll sort `False` as 0 and `True` as 1.)

It was implemented this way so that if you sort a list containing various types, like types will be sorted together. In Python 3 forward, however, this was changed and you can no longer implicitly compare dissimilar types.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, there existed an arbitrary but predictable comparison of values with different types. I think it was something like lexicographic comparison of the type name (ints < floats < strs < tuples ).

Answer (score 0):

It is correct according to Python's definition of ordering:

```
>>> 3 < "blah"
True
>>> 300 < 'zzz'
True
```

The [rule](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) is:

> If both are numbers, they are converted to a common type. Otherwise, objects of different types always compare unequal, and are ordered consistently but arbitrarily.